# show a popup menu when I left click on a button in oracle form

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have created a popup menu and assigned it into a button,when i right click 
the button the popup menu will be displayed.Now i want if i normally click the 
button that is left click the popup menu to be displayed

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? Right-click for menu is an established UI convention. It's what users expect. Changing the behavior will confuse and/or annoy your users.

Comment: yes i want to do this Exercise Urgently

Comment: any idea to do that ?

Comment: No. I think the behavior of popup menu is baked into Forms: if you have defined a popup menu for an item right-click displays it. Left-mouse button does something else. You could intercept which mouse-button was pressed in an ON-MOUSE-CLICK but there's no Forms PL/SQL command to render the popup menu.

Answer (score 1):

It works in Oracle Forms 6:

```
declare
  w_id pls_integer;
begin
  w_id := GET_ITEM_PROPERTY(Find_Item('CONTROL.B_REPORTS'), WINDOW_HANDLE);
  WIN_API_SHELL.SendMessage( w_id, 516 );  -- WM_RBUTTONDOWN
  WIN_API_SHELL.SendMessage( w_id, 517 );  -- WM_RBUTTONUP
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with @APC above; this is not a standard UI convention.  And it is not possible to override the default functionality of the right click menu within Forms.  **You could however**, build a small window/canvas/block made to look like the right click menu and default it's starting window position to be the mouse X,Y coordinate.